# Stat Multipliers: from Base Value or Iterative

Tags: game-design, software-engineering, game-mechanics

I'm aware similar questions have been asked before but this time I'm asking about a **specific** issue with the maths of stat modifiers.

I have a stat system that applies a list of modifiers to a stat, modifiers can either **shift** of **scale** a stat. Shifting is easy, you either add or remove a set value, scaling involves multiplying that value by a factor.

What I'm struggling to work out is the best way to multiply. The simple method is to let each scaling modifier simply stack, e.g. if we have 2 modifiers: x1.5 and x2 to a stat of 1 we get:

**Stacked**

```
(1 * 1.5) * 2 = 3
```

The alternative is to have each modifier apply to the base number and then be added, soas with the previous example we get a situation where we workout how much the base is multiplied by and then remove the base to get the new addition:

**From Base**

```
1 + ((1 * 1.5) - 1) + (1 * 2) - 1) = 2.5
```

In this way each modifier acts on the base value so that you can *guaranty* a 50% increase in a stat won't cause a ridiculous increase and that a modifier isn't affected by the order that it's applied in. Mainly it's this ordering I'm worried about, this becomes evident when you add shifting, e.g. we have 3 modifiers: +1, x1.5 and x2, with the first method:

**Stacked**

```
((1 + 1) * 1.5) * 2 = 6
```

Where as with the second method:

**From Base**

```
(1 + 1)  + ((1 * 1.5) - 1) + ((1 * 2) - 1) = 3.5
```

It doesn't take too much to see that in the stacked method if the shift/addition were applied after the multipliers it would not result in the same value.

How do other games approach this problem? What is the best decision to make here?

Comment: aka stack (you from base) vs. compound (your stack) the boost,

Comment: This a design decision, it's really up to you.

Comment: Well this is also a design question. But the problem is more than a design issue, it could potentially be a big issue but I'm not sure how big an issue and I'm looking for advice on where to move next, or examples of how this might affect game play.

Comment: D&D 3rd ed. uses the second approach, as one data point. It's largely a balance thing. Another option (partially also used by D&D) is to just not even allow stacking (D&D allows stacking of bonuses but only if they're from different categories, e.g. you can get both an "enhancement" bonus to a stat and a "natural" bonus to a stat but you can't have two stacked "enhancement" bonuses to the same stat, and any time two such bonuses are applicable you just take the bigger one).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How many stat modifiers do you expect to be applied to these stats by the final part of the game?  Is there a limit to how high these stats can go?  Does the player gain these stat modifiers frequently or rarely?  Do you want each new modifier to have a minor or major effect on the stats?  Since we don't know anything else about your game, it seems that you should pick whichever approach satisfies your answers to these questions.

The **stacked** approach that you described makes each cumulative modifier have a dramatic effect on an already boosted stat. For example, having five ***x2*** modifiers would multiply a stat by 32.  Add just one more ***x2*** modifier, and the stat is multiplied by 64! This might be alright if stat modifiers are very rare, or if there is some sort of limit to how many stat modifiers can be applied to the same stat.  However, this will make unboosted stats look completely pathetic in comparison to any kind of boosted stat.  Basically this method would make stats grow exponentially, like so:

[image: Exponential Curve]

On the other hand, the **from base** approach gives each individual modifier the same effect on the stat.  In this case, having five ***x2*** modifiers would only result in the stat being multiplied by 5.  Adding another one would increase the total multiplier to 6.  This method would probably work better if you don't want multiple stat modifiers to have such a dramatic effect on stats.  This method provides a more linear form of growth for stats, like so:

[image: Linear Curve]

It would probably be easier to manage the **from base** approach in terms of balancing the game, but ultimately it is up to you to decide which approach fits your game better.